# Linq query returns 0 count when join with related tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to query a table and join related tables. A single query without joining another table returns the expected result. but once I join another table I get zero result.

The below query returns some results

```
  var response = from o in context.Orders.Where(p => p.Start_Effective >= startDate && p.Start_Effective < endDate);
```

But once I join another table

```
var response = from o in context.Orders.Where(p => p.Start_Effective >= startDate && p.Start_Effective < endDate);
join v in context.Venue on o.Id equals v.Id
                        select new
                           {
                               Id = o.Id,
                               PointId = o.FromPointId,
                               VenueName = v.Name
                            };
```

I also try the below query and I still get zero result

```
var response = from o in context.Orders.Where(p => p.Start_Effective >= startDate && p.Start_Effective < endDate) 
                           from v in context.Venue
                           where v.OrderId == o.Id
                           select new
                           {
                               Id = o.Id,
                               PointId = o.FromPointId,
                               VenueName = v.Name
                            };
```

I cant figure out why this is returning 0 result once I join table

Comment: Do you have records in Orders table where id is same as Venue id?

Comment: Perhaps you need a left join instead of an inner join

Comment: Its a list and some corresponding order query are null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use a left join, and add to list

```
var response = (from o in contextOrders
  join v in context.Venue on o.Id equals v.Id into vj
   from v in vj.DefaultIfEmpty()
 where ( o.Start_Effective >= startDate && o.Start_Effective < endDate) 
  select new
 {
    Id = o.Id,
    PointId = o.FromPointId,
   VenueName = v.Name
 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no record in `Venue` Table with `OrderId`, when `inner join` is used, no data returned and you should insert a record that has `OrderId` that exist in `Order` Table.

Another option is using `left join`.
By left join, if there is no `OrderId` in `Venue` Table, result was returned